# Metal Depth Clamping

Tags: metal, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

I want to disable clamping between far and close points. Already tred to modify sampler to disable clamp to edge (`constexpr sampler s(address::clamp_to_zero)` and it worked as expected for the edges, but coordinates between most far and close points are still clamping.

Current unwanted result:
https://gph.is/g/ZyWjkzW

Expected result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZhbv.jpg

Also tried `encoder.setDepthClipMode(.clip)` but it didn't worked.

Some portions of code:

```
    let descriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .rgba16Float
    descriptor.colorAttachments[1].pixelFormat = .rgba16Float
    descriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = .invalid
```

---

```
let descriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = outputColorTexture
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = clearColor
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .load
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
    descriptor.colorAttachments[1].texture = outputDepthTexture
    descriptor.colorAttachments[1].clearColor = clearColor
    descriptor.colorAttachments[1].loadAction = .load
    descriptor.colorAttachments[1].storeAction = .store
    descriptor.renderTargetWidth = Int(drawableSize.width)
    descriptor.renderTargetHeight = Int(drawableSize.height)

    guard let encoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor) else { throw RenderingError.makeDescriptorFailed }
    encoder.setDepthClipMode(.clip)
    encoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
    encoder.setFragmentTexture(inputColorTexture, index: 0)
    encoder.setFragmentTexture(inputDepthTexture, index: 1)
    encoder.setFragmentBuffer(uniformsBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    encoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4)
    encoder.endEncoding()
```

Comment: It's not an issue of depth clipping/clamping, as the primitives (triangles) you want removed are not closest or farthest in depth. Instead, you should not create triangles in the area you don't want rendered.

Comment: @Itai Any ideas how is it possible not to draw primitives on those (or specific) areas?